# how to send data from one cursor to another and save in sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite

i have two listviews each one of them is in a different activity and im using intent to send each row from the first listview to the other one the intent works great but when i open the second activity nothing get saved to my database here is my code:

```
Main Activity(the first Activity)

listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, cc.class);
                    intent.putExtra("EXTRAKEY_ID",l);// THIS ADDED
                    startActivity(intent);
                    fav_name = getAllDataInCurrentLocale.getString(getAllDataInCurrentLocale.getColumnIndex(FAVOURITES_COL_NAME));
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, fav_name+" Added To Favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return true;
                }

            });
```

```
CC Activity(The Second Activity)

        fav_id = getIntent().getLongExtra("EXTRAKEY_ID", 0);
        manageFavouritesListView();









if (fav_id==0){


}



        getDataInCurrentLocaleById = dbSqlite.getDataInCurrentLocaleById(this,fav_id);
            if (getDataInCurrentLocaleById.moveToFirst()) {
                fav_name = getDataInCurrentLocaleById.getString(getDataInCurrentLocaleById.getColumnIndex(FAVOURITES_COL_NAME));


            }

        getDataInCurrentLocaleById.close();


        }






    private void manageFavouritesListView() {
        getDataInCurrentLocaleById = dbSqlite.getDataInCurrentLocaleById(this,fav_id);
        if (favourites_adapter == null) {
            favourites_adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    R.layout.textview2,
                    getDataInCurrentLocaleById,
                    new String[]{FAVOURITES_COL_NAME},
                    new int[]{R.id.textview10},
                    0

            );
            listView1.setAdapter(favourites_adapter);
            favourites_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            setListViewHandler(listView1);

        } else {
            favourites_adapter.swapCursor(getDataInCurrentLocaleById);

        }
    }
```

```
My DataBase(DB_Sqlite)

public class DB_Sqlite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String BDname = "data.db";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1; /*<<<<< ADDED BUT NOT NEEDED */
    public static final String TABLE_FAVOURITES = "mytable";


    public static final String FAVOURITES_COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID; /*<<<< use the Android stock ID name*/
    public static final String FAVOURITES_COL_NAME = "name";
    public static final String FAVOURITES_COL_FAVOURITEFLAG = "favourite_flag"; /*<<<<< NEW COLUMN */

    public DB_Sqlite(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, BDname, null, DBVERSION /*<<<<< used constant above */);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_FAVOURITES + " (" +
                FAVOURITES_COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + /*<<<<< AUTOINCREMENT NOT NEEDED AND IS INEFFICIENT */
                FAVOURITES_COL_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                FAVOURITES_COL_FAVOURITEFLAG + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0" + /*<<<<< COLUMN ADDED */
                ")");
        /* CHANGES HERE BELOW loop adding all Resource names NOT VALUES */
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        for (String s: StringResourcesHandling.getAllStringResourceNames()) {
            cv.clear();
            cv.put(FAVOURITES_COL_NAME,s);
            db.insert(TABLE_FAVOURITES,null,cv);


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_FAVOURITES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public boolean insertData(long id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(FAVOURITES_COL_ID, id);
        long result = db.insert("favorite",null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }




    /* Getting everything and make MatrixCursor VALUES from Resource names from Cursor with Resource names  */
    public Cursor getAllDataInCurrentLocale(Context context) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_FAVOURITES,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        if (csr.getCount() < 1) return csr;
        MatrixCursor mxcsr = new MatrixCursor(csr.getColumnNames(),csr.getCount());
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            mxcsr.addRow(convertCursorRow(context,csr,new String[]{FAVOURITES_COL_NAME}));
        }
        csr.close();
        return mxcsr;
    }
    public Cursor getDataInCurrentLocaleById(Context context, long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String wherepart = FAVOURITES_COL_ID + "=?";
        String[] args = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_FAVOURITES,null,wherepart,args,null,null,null);
        if (csr.getCount() < 1) return csr;
        MatrixCursor mxcsr = new MatrixCursor(csr.getColumnNames(),csr.getCount());
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            mxcsr.addRow(convertCursorRow(context,csr,new String[]{FAVOURITES_COL_NAME}));
        }
        csr.close();
        return mxcsr;
    }

    /* This getting columns from Cursor into String array (no BLOB handleing)*/
    public String[] convertCursorRow(Context context, Cursor csr, String[] columnsToConvert) {
        String[] rv = new String[csr.getColumnCount()];
        for (String s: csr.getColumnNames()) {
            boolean converted = false;
            for (String ctc: columnsToConvert) {
                if (csr.getType(csr.getColumnIndex(s)) == Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB) {
                    //........ would have to handle BLOB here if needed (another question if needed)
                }
                if (ctc.equals(s)) {
                    rv[csr.getColumnIndex(s)] = StringResourcesHandling.getStringByName(context,csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(s)));
                    converted = true;
                }
            } if (!converted) {
                rv[csr.getColumnIndex(s)] = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(s));
            }
        }
        return rv;
    }

    }
```

i dont know what is the problem please help thank u in advance

Comment: You need to save the data from the first activity to the Database, not try and put it in the cursor.

Comment: @Blundell please can explain more what do u mean, because the first activity gets the data from the database